# Mostrar datos en gráfica con chartjs llenando dataset con llamada http

Tags: typescript, vue3, composition-api

Debo mostrar una gráfica, usando vue 3 y composition API, con la que debo lleno un dataset con los datos que traigo de una llamada http, si lleno el dataset con datos estáticos la tabla se muestra correctamente pero si la lleno con los datos traídos de la llamda se muestra vacía, he intentando usar la variable reactiva y el método watch pero por lo visto no lo estoy implementando correctamente, comparto el  ¿alguna idea de cómo puedo implementar el método watch o una propieda reactiva para que la gráfica se actualice de forma dinámica?:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import axios from 'axios'
import { onMounted, onUnmounted, reactive, watch } from 'vue'
import {
  Chart as ChartJS, 
  Title,
  Tooltip, 
  Legend,
  BarElement,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale
} from 'chart.js'
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'

const cpu = reactive({
  labels: [''],
  datasets: [
    { 
      label: 'Consumo',    
      backgroundColor: '#f87979',    
      barThickness: 40,    
      borderRadius: 5,    
      data: [0]    
    }    
  ]    
})
    
ChartJS.register(CategoryScale, LinearScale, BarElement, Title, Tooltip, Legend)


const urlGraficas: string =

  import.meta.env.VITE_APP_ROOT_API + import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_DASHBOARD_DESA + '/graficas'       
async function pedirGraficas()     
  const responseGraficaCpu = await axios.get<any>(urlGraficas + 'Cpu')    
  console.log(responseGraficaCpu.data)    
  responseGraficaCpu.data.forEach((element: { cuando: string; usu: string; cpu: number }) => {    
    cpu.labels.push(element.cuando)    
    cpu.datasets[0].data.push(element.cpu)    
  })    
  cpu.labels.shift()    
  cpu.datasets[0].data.shift()        
}        
watch(    
  () => cpu,    
  async () => {
 //todo when the object it is fill        
  }    
)        
const io = {    
  labels: [    
    'Enero',    
    'Febrero',    
    'Marzo',    
    'Abril',    
    'Mayo',    
    'Junio',    
    'Julio',    
    'Augosto',    
    'Septiembre',    
    'Octubre',    
    'Noviembre',    
    'Deciembre'    
  ],    
  datasets: [    
    {    
      label: 'Consumo',    
      backgroundColor: '#f87979',    
      barThickness: 40,    
      borderRadius: 5,    
      data: [5, 27, 63, 32, 71, 40, 39, 40, 2, 19, 12, 38]    
    }    
  ]    
}    

const options = { 
  responsive: true,    
  maintainAspectRatio: true    
}        
onMounted(async () => {    
  await pedirGraficas()      
})    

let graficas: Element[] = reactive([])    

</script>
```